# ASP.NET Identity - How to get a dropdown list of all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Have have added Fullname to my identity user claim here:

```
public string Fullname { get { return this.Firstname + " " + this.Lastname; } }
```

now I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist (Full names) of all the users

In my controller i have :

```
      var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("*");
        SelectList list = new SelectList(users);
        ViewBag.Users = list;
```

and in my view I have:

```
   @Html.DropDownList("Users", ViewBag.Users as SelectList);
```

But I get an error highlighting the "Users" in my view.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type
>   'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Users'.'

Is there a better way to archive what i'm trying to do? please help

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
@Html.DropDownList("Users", "Users list");
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help -- unfortunately that is not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a List like below. Choose a proper value for Text and Value.

```
var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("*");
    var list = users.Select(x => new SelectListItem(){ Text = x.FullName, Value = x.FullName);
    ViewBag.Users = list;
```

Comment: Hello Richard,  thanks a lot, however I'm getting an error at { Text = x.Fullname, Value = x.Fullname) Text and value text should obviouly be Fullname and value should be userId --- there seem to be an red underline that  says that i'm missiong a directive

Comment: It looks like users is just an array of string, you'll need full User objects to get their fullname. `Membership.GetAllUsers();` might be a better way to populate your users object

Comment: i'm using identity

Comment: What type of object do you get from `var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("*");`

Comment: --- var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("*"); gives the error highlighted in the question, I though there would be a better way to get the list of users in a drop down

Comment: It sounds like you get an error from your View, not from your controller. What is the return type of `Roles.GetUsersInRole("*")`

Answer (score 0):

[`Roles.GetUsersInRole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.roles.getusersinrole?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns `string[]` array, you can use overloaded [`Enumerable.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) method to create `SelectList` from it:

```
var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("RoleName");
var list = users.Select((x, index) => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = index.ToString() });
ViewBag.Users = list;
```

An alternative to get `SelectList` from user with specified role should be like this:

```
var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("RoleName").Select(Membership.GetUser).ToList();
var list = users.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.UserName, Value = Membership.GetUser(x.UserName).ProviderUserKey.ToString() }).ToList();
ViewBag.Users = list;
```

**Note:** For ASP.NET Identity 2, you may use `Users` and `Roles` with data context to create `SelectList` as in example below:

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var users = from u in context.Users
        where u.Roles.Any(r => r.Role.Name == "RoleName")
        select u;

    // ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(users, "Id", "UserName");
    ViewBag.Users = users.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.UserName, Value = x.Id }).ToList();
}
```